# reuse padding when installing new carpet

Tags: basement, carpet

A new carpet has to be installed instead of the old one. Is it possible to reuse padding and/or tack strips, or this is not recommended?

Comment: Some carpet companies won't warrant their product over old pad.

Answer (score 1):

To me, this seems like a "penny-wise, pound-foolish" place to save a few pennies. *But then, I tend to rip out carpets and replace them with hard surfaces.*

Consider that whatever spills, grunge or general nastiness that got through the old carpet are in the pad - and consider that the pad is already somewhat compressed in the wear areas. You're giving away a good deal of the "new-carpet experience" by leaving a dirty old half-flat pad under it.

Tack strips I don't feel as strongly about reusing.

Comment: thanks for comment. I thought about the same on reusing pads.